# Complete exceptionnally a middle CompletableStage

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I'm performing some heavy work as follows:

```java
try {
    Input in = initInput(param);
    Result re = doHeavyWork(in);
    saveResultSomewhereElse(re);
} catch (Exception e) {
    logExecutionError(e);
}
```

Furthermore, sometimes the `doHeavyWork` takes too long that we ought to kill it manually to save resources. Nevertheless, I'd like to do `logExecutionError` in that case.

Transforming the code block above into `CompletableFuture`, we might get:

```java
CompletableFuture.completedFuture(param)
                 .thenApply(initInput)
                 .thenApplyAsync(doHeavyWork, dedicatedExecutorService)
                 .thenApply(saveResultSomewhereElse)
                 .exceptionally(logExecutionError);
```

My question is that if I terminate the `dedicatedExecutorService`, will the heavy work be really killed and the `logExecutionError` is guaranteed to execute?

Comment: you mean if you call `dedicatedExecutorService.shutDownNow()`? If so, this is trivial to find out?

Comment: In general, `CompletableFuture` has a method `cancel`, but it does not "interrupt" anything (read its documentation carefully). On the other hand `shutDownNow` on an executor will interrupt the worker thread, _if_ such an interrupt is supported. So if your logic in the `doHeavyWork` supports interrupts you can call that method; but that will open new problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. The somewhat longer answer is that there is no good way to terminate a thread in Java unless it cooperates. [Thread#stop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()) should not be used and is not available on [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). When you shutdown an executor service it can ask jobs to stop by interrupting them, but it cannot force them to stop. If `doHeavyWork` handles interrupts and stops, then it will exit gracefully or with an exception (depending on how you have designed it) and the next stage can proceed.

Honestly I'm not sure if the code in `thenApply` will run if the executor service has been stopped. Personally I would stop and interrupt `doHeavyWork` without stopping the pool. Then you are in full control and can keep the executor service for other tasks.

Comment: "stop and interrupt doHeavyWork" how exactly would you plan to do this? the work is done in the `CompletableFuture` worker thread.

Comment: A https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html for stopping gracefully is a good start. If the job needs to be interrupted as well (to stop I/O for example) it could save the Thread somewhere when it starts so that it is available when it needs to be interrupted. If doHeavyWork switches among multiple threads internally and not just one things get really hairy, but if it is single-threaded it can just save the thread and expose a method that can be called from the outside.

Comment: OP is using an ExecutorService to begin with. Your proposal is to use an `AtomicBoolean` (a `volatile` would be more appropriate, but OK) to signal a "stop". So if there are 2 CompletableFutures that use the same pool, how will you plan to distinguish between threads that must stop and not? You will have to somehow bound each `AtomicBoolean` to the thread. I would like to see how that is doable. Also notice that OP really wants to interrupt the `doHeavyWork`, while your flag is not an interruption. This is by far not as easy as this answer suggests.

Comment: Overall, what OP wants to achieve is really not possible. `CompletableFuture` has `cancel`, but it will only set the result of that future, the underlying task will still happy keep executing. I honestly do not know of a good way to handle this, in general. I have seen (understandable really) such scenarios where "killing" tasks is required, but I do not know a (good) way to do it, if such exists at all.

Comment: @Eugene I did write that the short answer is NO? There is no general solution, but if doHeavyWork can be adapted it may be possible to ask it to stop or (failing that) to interrupt it. To interrupt one must get hold of the thread, which is not known in advance but which might be exposed. To request it to stop the idea with the AtomicBoolean was to pass in an instance and then change the value from the outside. One cannot pass in a volatile boolean and later change it. One could  expose a setter for a volatile boolean though.

Comment: I mostly agree with your follow-up. "To interrupt one must get hold of the thread, which is not known in advance but which might be exposed" - this and the `AtomicBoolean` means that the thread must always check this flag. This is very different then calling `interrupt`, right? And by "kill" this is it OP means and that is why the question mentioned "My question is that if I terminate the `dedicatedExecutorService`". Users want to be able to really kill a started task, with an interruption. I'll stop commenting under your answer, thank you for all the follow-ups.

Comment: @Eugene (I'll also stop but want to respond with this) an interrupt will not kill a task as it can be ignored. As I wrote stop has been deprecated and interrupt does not kill a thread; it simply interrupts I/O and flags the thread for interruption, but if it is busy working with computation it might not notice. Just as with a stop flag the worker needs to cooperate. The OP really wants kill/stop, but that does not exist. My answer tries to come up with something that works and is good enough. Cheers :-).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will find another way to control the execution from external infrastructure.